# Given a parallelogram $ABCD$, if $B=(-3,-4)$, $C=(-7,-7)$, and $A=(0,0)$, what is the area of the parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, area, quadrilateral

> Given a parallelogram $ABCD$ lies in the $xy$ plane. The coordinates of point $B$ are $(-3,-4)$ and the coordinates of point $C$ are $(-7,-7)$, and $A$ are $(0,0)$. What is the area of the parallelogram?

This is a GRE practice question and I've struggled to answer it.

I am also a bit confused about this solution: Area of parallelogram = 2 * Triangle ABD. They say that if one of the vertices of a triangle is at the origin and the other two being $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$, then the area of the triangle can be written as:

Area of triangle $ABD = |\frac{ad-bc}{2}| = |\frac{(-3)(-7) - (-4)(-7)}{2}| = \frac{7}{2}.$

So the area of parallelogram is $7$.

Can anyone please explain to me how they got this formula? Also, are there alternate methods to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that in the question it's assumed that $A$ is the origin and in the solution $ABC$ is typed as $ABD$.

Comment: Yes, I've made an edit.

Comment: What is a GRE practice question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two vectors $u=(a,b), v=(c,d)$ in $R^2$ the area of the parallelogram with sides u and v is given by the abcolute value of the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#2_%C3%97_2_matrices)

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{vmatrix}=|ad-bc|$$

and the area of the triangle with sides u and v is given by

$$\frac12\begin{vmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{vmatrix}=\frac12|ad-bc|$$

[image]